# Multithreaded Perl script leads to broken pipe if called as a Python subprocess

Tags: python, multithreading, perl, subprocess

I am calling a Perl script from Python 3.7.3, with subprocess. The Perl script that is called is this one:

https://github.com/moses-smt/mosesdecoder/blob/master/scripts/tokenizer/tokenizer.perl

And the code I am using to call it is:

```py
import sys
import os
import subprocess
import threading

def copy_out(source, dest):
    for line in source:
        dest.write(line)

num_threads=4

args = ["perl", "tokenizer.perl",
        "-l", "en",
        "-threads", str(num_threads)
       ]

with open(os.devnull, "wb") as devnull:
    tokenizer = subprocess.Popen(args,
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=devnull)

tokenizer_thread = threading.Thread(target=copy_out, args=(tokenizer.stdout, open("outfile", "wb")))
tokenizer_thread.start()

num_lines = 100000

for _ in range(num_lines):
    tokenizer.stdin.write(b'Random line.\n')

tokenizer.stdin.close()
tokenizer_thread.join()

tokenizer.wait()
```

On my system, this leads to the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 27, in <module>
    tokenizer.stdin.write(b'Random line.\n')
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I investigated this, and it turns out that if the `-threads` argument for the subprocess is 1 the error is not thrown. As I don't want to give up on multithreading in the child process, my question is:

**What is causing this error in the first place? "Who" is to blame for it: OS / environment, my Python code, the Perl code?**

I am glad to provide more information if needed.

---

**EDIT**: To respond to some comments,

- Running the Perl script is only possible if you also have this file: https://github.com/moses-smt/mosesdecoder/blob/master/scripts/share/nonbreaking_prefixes/nonbreaking_prefix.en
- The Perl script actually processes several thousands of lines before the process fails. In my Python script above, if I make `num_lines` smaller, I do not get this error anymore.
- If I invoke this Perl script simply on the command line, without any Python, it works fine: <s>no matter how many (Perl) threads</s> or lines of input.
- My Python variable `num_threads` only controls the number of threads of the Perl subprocess. I never start several Python threads, just one.

---

**EDIT 2**: In my first edit, I incorrectly stated that this Perl program runs fine when called with e.g. `-threads 4` from the command line: there, a different Perl was used that is compiled with multithreading. If I use the same Perl that is invoked from Python, I get:

```
$ cat [file with 100000 lines] | [correct perl] tokenizer.perl -l en -threads 4
Can't locate object method "new" via package "Thread" at
tokenizer.perl line 130, <STDIN> line 8000.
```

Which no doubt would have helped me debug this better.

Comment: Broken pipe means the Perl process closed an output stream that the Python process tried to read from. Would need to see the Perl script to diagnose it further.

Comment: @mob Thanks for your comment! I did link to this Perl script: https://github.com/moses-smt/mosesdecoder/blob/master/scripts/tokenizer/tokenizer.perl

Comment: Have you checked that the [`load_prefixes()`](https://github.com/moses-smt/mosesdecoder/blob/master/scripts/tokenizer/tokenizer.perl#L548) sub does not die before the input loop is even started? It seems to refer to a `$prefixfile` variable, which file might not exist?

Comment: @HåkonHægland Hi, thanks for the tip! This file definitely exists, as the Perl process does not fail immediately: it does process several thousands of lines before failing.

Comment: @MathiasMüller How did you install that file? If I can get it, I can test more..

Comment: @HåkonHægland It's included in my case because I clone this entire repo. The particular file is here: https://github.com/moses-smt/mosesdecoder/blob/master/scripts/share/nonbreaking_prefixes/nonbreaking_prefix.en. Sorry, I did not think about this!

Comment: Ok, I can see now that the SIGPIPE is raised after 8000 iterations in the `for` loop of the Python script

Comment: And the `copy_out()` thread blocks immediately, so it does not read any lines from `source`. And running the script with `strace` shows: `write(5, "Random line.\nRandom line.\nRandom"..., 4095) = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
--- SIGPIPE {si_signo=SIGPIPE, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=23702, si_uid=1000}`

Comment: @HåkonHægland I am not sure what this means: are you saying that my Python code is the culprit here, and that the Python threading should be written differently? If so, how? Please consider explanding your comment to an answer.

Comment: It seems like the `copy_out()` thread just dies after a while (i don't know why yet), and then the Python `for` loop still tries to write to write to the pipe with `tokenizer.stdin.write(b'Random line.\n')` and since the other end of the pipe has shut down, you get the SIGPIPE signal.

Comment: @zdim: (1) Yes, it runs fine if called on its own, no matter how many (Perl) threads or how many lines of input. I've run it countless times. (2) Just to clarify: you mean, without `tokenizer_thread` in my Python code?

Comment: @zdim If I run it with my Python variable `num_threads=1` it runs fine. This implies that the `-threads` argument for the Perl script is also 1, and that it runs single-threaded.

Comment: @mob, You have it backwards. Reading from  a closed pipe returns EOF. It's writing to a closed pipe returns EPIPE (Broken pipe). In all likelihood, the child process's STDIN being closed means the child process exited. **So one should should check why the Perl program exited** before the Pythong program expected it to. **What was its exit code? What error did it send to STDERR?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the perl script crashes if `perl` does not support threads. You can check if your `perl` supports threads by running:

```
perl -MConfig -E 'say "Threads supported" if $Config{useithreads}'
```

In my case, the output was empty so I installed a new perl with thread support:

```
perlbrew install perl-5.30.0 --as=5.30.0-threads -Dusethreads
perlbrew use 5.30.0-threads
```

Then I ran the Python script again:

```
import sys
import os
import subprocess
import threading

def copy_out(source, dest):
    for line in iter(source.readline, b''):
        dest.write(line)

num_threads=4
args = ["perl", "tokenizer.perl",
        "-l", "en",
        "-threads", str(num_threads)
       ]
tokenizer = subprocess.Popen(
    args,
    bufsize=-1,  #use default bufsize = 8192 bytes
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)

tokenizer_thread = threading.Thread(
    target=copy_out, args=(tokenizer.stdout, open("outfile", "wb")))
tokenizer_thread.start()

num_lines = 100000

for _ in range(num_lines):
    tokenizer.stdin.write(b'Random line.\n')

tokenizer.stdin.close()
tokenizer_thread.join()
tokenizer.wait()
```

and it now ran to the end with no errors and produced the output file `outfile` with 100000 lines.

Comment: I had the same problem and using a different Perl worked! Thank you for this awesome analysis. I incorrectly stated that this Perl program runs fine when called with e.g.  `-threads 4` form the command line: there, a different Perl was used that is compiled with multithreading.

Answer (score 2):

> *What is causing this error in the first place?*

Writing to a closed pipe causes the OS to send `SIGPIPE` to the process calling `write`. This allows program to work as generators. For example, the following won't run forever despite containing an infinite loop, because `head` will exit and close its STDIN after reading ten lines, leading to `perl` receiving a SIGPIPE.

```
perl -le'1 while print ++$i;' | head
```

If the `SIGPIPE` signal is being ignored, the `write` system call will return `EPIPE` (Broken pipe) instead. The following won't run forever either because `print` returns error `EPIPE` once `head` exits.

```sh
perl -le'$SIG{PIPE}="IGNORE"; 1 while print ++$i;' | head
```

From the fact that your Python program received an `EPIPE` error, we deduce two facts:

- The Python program ignores `SIGPIPE` signals, and
- All handles to the reader end of the pipe were closed.

So we must ask ourselves: Why would the Perl program close its STDIN? it's very unlikely that its STDIN was closed explicitly. By far, the most likely explanation is that the child process was terminated.

> *"Who" is to blame for it: OS / environment, my Python code, the Perl code?*

That depends on what caused the Perl program to exit. The first thing to do is figure out what exit status was returned by the child process. Depending on the exit status, we'll know whether

- the process was killed by a signal,
- the process exited with an error, or
- the process completed successfully.

If the exit code tells us the process was killed by a signal, the exit code will also tells us by which signal. This could give us some information. (This would be the hardest of the three scenarios to debug.)

If the exit code tells us the process returned an error, the error code itself might not contain any additional useful information, but an error message was surely sent to the child's STDERR to provide more information.

If the exit code tells us the process completed successfully, perhaps the arguments or input you are providing don't mean what you think they mean.

So make sure to call `tokenizer.wait()` to collect the exit status and store it in `tokenizer.returncode`. Also make sure to log what is being sent to STDERR.

Comment: Thank you for your very insightful answer! The problem was a version of Perl that does not work with multithreading, but your advice would definitely have helped to debug.